# Collecting high volume DNS stats with libpcap

Tags: dns, monitoring, libpcap

I am considering writing an application to monitor DNS requests for approximately 200,000 developer and test machines.  Libpcap sounds like a good starting point, but before I dive in I was hoping for feedback.

This is what the application needs to do:

- Inspect all DNS packets.
- Keep aggregate statistics.  Include:

  1. DNS name.
  2. DNS record type.
  3. Associated IP(s).
  4. Requesting IP.
  5. Count.
- If the number of requesting IPs for one DNS name is > 10, then stop keeping the client ip.

The stats would hopefully be kept in memory, and disk writes would only occur when a new, "suspicious" DNS exchange occurs, or every few hours to write the new stats to disk for consumption by other processes.

My question are:
  1.  Do any applications exist that can do this?  The link will be either 100 MB or 1 GB.
  2.  Performance is the #1 consideration by a large margin.  I have experience writing c for other one-off security applications, but I am not an expert.  Do any tips come to mind?
  3.  How much of an effort would this be for a good c developer in man-hours?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try something like [DNSCAP](https://www.dns-oarc.net/tools/dnscap) or even [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) for capturing DNS traffic.

BTW I think this is rather a superuser.com question than a StackOverflow one.